# Facing Issues with slash keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsurl

I am working on an iOS Chat app. I want to use slash Keyboard. Can you guide me how i get the gif image to use in my iOS programming. Actually the link that I am getting after selecting an gif from slash Keyboard file is not providing me Image in code. Please guide me.

for eg
 http://tapslash.com/m/giphy/NycV9yzKiiBR6
this is a gif link ,but i am getting unable to get image in Xcode.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tapslash.com/m/giphy/10k8HMhtzzk73W"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

always getting image nil

Comment: try https instead of http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not a link to an image, put to a web page containing the image. Do get NSData from the link, it needs to end in a .gif or similar. In your sample code, I would change it to

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media0.giphy.com/media/10k8HMhtzzk73W/giphy.gif"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

If you have the URL `http://tapslash.com/m/giphy/10k8HMhtzzk73W`, then to get it do a .gif url you have to get that part at the end.

```
NSArray *splitURL = [stringContainingURL componentsSeparatedBy:@"/"];
NSString *identifier = [splitURL lastObject]; // Written in browser, not sure if exists. If not use [splitURL objectAtIndex:splitURL.count - 1];

NSString *goodURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://media0.giphy.com/media/%@/giphy.gif", identifier];

// Should return:  http://media0.giphy.com/media/10k8HMhtzzk73W/giphy.gif
```

Comment: Thanx Minebomber for response.This url link i got after coping the gif from slash keyboard.

Comment: @atulawasthi I added an example of what the code might look like. (I haven't used slash so it might be different.)

Comment: Thanx Minebomber for response can you also provide me help regarding url of Sticker sharing with shahs keyboard Right now i am getting the path Like following "http://tapslash.com/m/sticker/5dd31073-94f8-47c1-b362-ece3834cfbd3" but unable to get the NSData from that url plz

Comment: Sorry, as I stated before, I can't help you with that. I don't work with slash, so I can't really help you

Comment: Its Ok Minebomber.Thnx for great support!